# can't connect local site to Iphone with XAMPP

Tags: iphone, xampp, wifi, local, connect

Ive build my site on wordpress and using xampp

i want to test my new dev site on my remotely on my iphone and ipad via wifi

They're both connected to wifi

When i search iphone http://000.000.0.00 or http://000.000.0.00:80, :8080
it comes up with a link to a folder , which is my true path 
when i click on this next sub folder , i loop back round to 127.0.0.1
As i guess iphone doesn't know where to find my site contents

I've tried renaming my wordpress site the with the http://ipaddress, :80, :80;80
ad it comes up with an error

ive found in my XAMPP index.php file

The footer seems to send me to 127.0.0.1/dashboard/
i can view this from my iphone

i've tried changing that footer on index.php to my site path 
As well as deleting the file all together
Deleting the file allowed me to access more folders but not into the subfolder where my site remains

I've read through questions and tutorials but can't seem to find a solution

i was wondering if i've missed something or if i  need to configure files in such a way , maybe to this index.php for XAMPP itself to get it to point at my site as a default

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if your files are in htdocs or you have given correct path to your working directory in your httpd.conf file.

If the directory is correct and you have run your php pages already, I suggest you use **ngrok** for remote connection to your localhost.

https://ngrok.com/download

it is simple to use.

to run it go to the directory of ngrok in cmd and type `ngrok http 80` while your XAMPP servers are running. It will provide a link that could be accessed through internet by any device.